# wlan0 does not appear in Ubuntu server and raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberrypi

I followed the instruction in answer for this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154768/can-you-install-ubuntu-on-the-raspberry-pi-4) to use Ubuntu server (64 bits) in my raspberry pi 4. It worked well, but I haven't been able to get the wifi interface available. It is, if I do `ifconfig -a`, only `eth0` and `lo` interfaces are shown. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with ubuntu 18.04.3 on a 3B+, but user chilli555 posted a link to this:

[b43 Wireless Driver Problems in Ubuntu Server 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160766/b43-wireless-driver-problems-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/1160855#1160855)

and it worked for me, except that I had to replace the name of the wlan interface from wlp1s0 to wlan0.